# Using CROP_HINTS of google vision

Tags: android, image, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am using google vision API to detect the face and crop the image accordingly.
this is my code to get the crop coordinates.but its returns the max size of bitmap image I have.

```
                Vision.Builder builder = new Vision.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null);
                builder.setVisionRequestInitializer(requestInitializer);

                Vision vision = builder.build();

                BatchAnnotateImagesRequest batchAnnotateImagesRequest =
                        new BatchAnnotateImagesRequest();
                batchAnnotateImagesRequest.setRequests(new ArrayList<AnnotateImageRequest>() {{
                    AnnotateImageRequest annotateImageRequest = new AnnotateImageRequest();

                    Image base64EncodedImage = new Image();
                    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, byteArrayOutputStream);
                    byte[] imageBytes = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();

                    base64EncodedImage.encodeContent(imageBytes);
                    annotateImageRequest.setImage(base64EncodedImage);

                    ArrayList<Feature> features = new ArrayList<>();
                      Feature cropHints = new Feature();
                    cropHints.setType("CROP_HINTS");
                    features.add(cropHints);
                    annotateImageRequest.setFeatures(features);


                    add(annotateImageRequest);
                }});

                Vision.Images.Annotate annotateRequest =
                        vision.images().annotate(batchAnnotateImagesRequest);

                BatchAnnotateImagesResponse response = annotateRequest.execute();
Sting vertices=response.getResponses().get(0).getCropHintsAnnotation().getCropHints().get(0).getBoundingPoly().getVertices().toString())

            }
```

the result of vertices

```
 [{}, {"x":841}, {"x":841,"y":1499}, {"y":1499}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want here is the *FACE_DETECTION* feature, and not *CROP_HINTS*. Try changing that in your API request and you will get the crop coordinates for the faces in your images.

You might then need to change how you process the response, but the API request will be providing the solution you need. I recommend you to test it [here](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate) using a JSON such as:

```
{
  "requests": [
    {
      "image": {
        "source": {
          "imageUri": "<YOUR_SAMPLE_IMAGE_URL>"
        }
      },
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "FACE_DETECTION"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I doing this in android

Comment: This was just to test that the API provides you with the proper face recognition. Regarding your Android code, just change *CROP_HINTS* for  *FACE_DETECTION* and change the way you process the response.

Comment: I now I am using FACE_DETECTION .I am not getting ,how to use this coordinates

Comment: Have you tried [the link I posted yesterday](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate)? There you can see more information about how the response should be processed. In short, you must process the *boundingPoly* object in the response, where you can find the 4 corners that frame the faces in your image.